# Issue with asynchronous javascript post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to simply set a ejs variable to data retrieved through an ajax post request every second. (refreshing a log) I have tried callback functions, and I feel like I am really close but can't seem to crack it.

Below is the javascript:

```
    function getResults(callback){     
        $.ajax({
            url: '/resultsRefresh',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: callback 
        })
    };

    function setResults(result) {
            console.log("result: " + result);
            document.getElementById("results") = result;
    };
    
    window.setInterval(getResults(setResults), 1000);
```

And this is the function in question being called on the node server:

```
function readResults(req, res) {
    return fs.readFileSync("./temp/results.txt", 'utf8');
}
```

which is coming through

```
webRouter.post("/resultsRefresh", readResults);
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using express as the `webRouter`?

Comment: So what is the issue

Comment: Any error in your console->network page?

Comment: Show us the callback, the problem could be in there.

Answer (score 2):

When responding to requests in the server, you are generally not supposed to return a value, rather you need to call a response function. When using express, [`res.sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) does the trick:

```js
function readResults(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./temp/results.txt');
}
```